# How to set the external IP location?

Tags: ip, external-ip

When I am setting the external IP in the GCP, I found out even if  I set the location at the asia-east1 the IP location is still in the US. I tried many times, but the location is always in the US.

Is there any way I can set the IP location to Taiwan?

Comment: How are you checking the location?

Comment: I use the ip tracker

Comment: can someone help me QQ

Comment: What is "ip tracker"? How do you know it has up-to-date information on IP locations?

Answer (score 1):

The Google IP’s are allocated in the US and then Google network is able to handle the geographic localization as indicated in GCP. It is also possible that the IP ranges change zone during time and that IP tracker can get confused.
[Here](https://groups.google.com/g/gce-discussion/c/otD1c6E-wWI/m/cvEDCUAlBAAJ) I found a discussion about this topic.